# Java special characters RegEx

Tags: java, regex

I want to achieve following using Regular expression in Java

```
String[] paramsToReplace = {"email", "address", "phone"};

//input URL string
String ip = "http://www.google.com?name=bob&email=okATtk.com&address=NYC&phone=007";

//output URL string
String op = "http://www.google.com?name=bob&email=&address=&phone=";
```

The URL can contain special characters like %

Answer (score 1):

Try this expression: `(email=)[^&]+` (replace `email` with your array elements) and replace with the group: `input.replaceAll("("+ paramsToReplace[i] + "=)[^&]+", "$1");`

```
 String input = "http://www.google.com?name=bob&email=okATtk.com&address=NYC&phone=007";
 String output = input;
 for( String param : paramsToReplace ) {
   output = output.replaceAll("("+ param + "=)[^&]+", "$1");
 }
```

Comment: This returns an incorrect output as follows : http://www.google.com?name=bob&email=&

Comment: @user1093296 I don't see any incorrect input. Could you specify? I get `http://www.google.com?name=bob&email=&address=&phone=` with my test, just like you required in your post.

Comment: Hi Thomas, It should also work for string like : String ip = "http://www.google.address?name=bob&email=address@tk.com&address=NYC&phone=007";
Where 'address' is appeared multiple times

Comment: @user1093296 as I said, my test returns the output you want (`op` in your post), so the error seems to be in your implementation.

Comment: @user1093296 id does, since `address=...` is replaced, thus `address?...` and `address@` don't match (`email=address@tk.com` would be replaced with `email=` since `email` is in your `paramsToReplace`). Test yourself.

Answer (score 0):

For the example above. you can use split

```
String[] temp = ip.split("?name=")[1].split("&")[0];
op = temp[0] + "?name=" + temp[1].split("&")[0] +"&email=&address=&phone=";
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
private final static String REPLACE_REGEX = "=.+\\&";
ip=ip+"&";
for(String param : paramsToReplace) {
    ip = ip.replaceAll(param+REPLACE_REGEX, Matcher.quoteReplacement(param+"=&"));
}
```

P.S. This is only a concept, i didn't compile this code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regular expressions to achieve that:

```
String op = ip;

for (String param : paramsToReplace) {
    int start = op.indexOf("?" + param);
    if (start < 0)
        start = op.indexOf("&" + param);
    if (start < 0)
        continue;
    int end = op.indexOf("&", start + 1);
    if (end < 0)
        end = op.length();
    op = op.substring(0, start + param.length() + 2) + op.substring(end);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works fine for most of the cases. But it gives wrong output for the following case :String[] paramsToReplace = {"email", "address", "phone"};
               String ip = "http://www.google.address?name=bob&email=address@tk.com&address=NYC&phone=007";

Comment: @user1093296: I should have thought of that. :$ Updated answer.